# automount dead but subsys locked

Tags: linux, centos, mount, automount

I am running a service "autofs" on a CentOS release 6.4.
After a while (2-3 days) I get this error:

```
automount dead but subsys locked
```

when I check the status.

Do you have any idea what provokes the error?

Answer (score 1):

According to the autofs init.d script I have here (and the `status` function from `/etc/init.d/functions`) it would seem that the process has died (or at least the pid file does not exist/is empty/etc.) but that the lock file (`/var/lock/subsys/autofs`) still exists.

That, presumably, means the `autofs` process has died for some reason. I would check its logs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! How to check its logs?

Comment: Offhand, I don't know. Look in `/var/logs` for files with autofs in the name? Look in syslog (`/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`, etc.). Look in the documentation and see if it mentions other places that it might log.

Answer (score 0):

Basically for any service when its running, it create lock and while running/starting if anything goes wrong, it stuck in dead condition with subsys locked.
In this case just check log what is the error, you can delete subsys locked file after going /var/lock/subsys path, but still there is no guaranty that service will start normally, to start service normally we need to clear issue stopping service to start, subsys will not play any role here.